Raycast not hitting enemy
I'm trying to make a player attack script so that when the mouse clicks on the enemy within a certain range it will call the attack enemy function (which then goes on to call a take Damage function from the enemyHealth script. However when I hit play and click on the enemy (that has a big enough collider to be detected by raycast and is well within the attackRange) it will not take damage.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;

public class PlayerAttack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int attackDamage = 10;
    public float attackRange = 1.5f;
    public LayerMask enemyLayer;

    public CinemachineVirtualCamera virtualCamera;
    private Camera cameraComponent;
    private CinemachineRecomposer recomposer;
    private Vector3 cameraOffset; // Variable to store the camera offset

    void Start()
    {
        cameraComponent = virtualCamera.GetComponentInChildren<Camera>();
        recomposer = virtualCamera.GetComponent<CinemachineRecomposer>();
        var cameraOffsetComponent = virtualCamera.GetComponent<CinemachineCameraOffset>();

        if (cameraComponent == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Camera component not found on the virtual camera.");
        }
        if (recomposer == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("CinemachineRecomposer component not found on the virtual camera.");
        }
        if (cameraOffsetComponent != null)
        {
            // Set the camera offset values
            cameraOffsetComponent.m_Offset.y = 7.67f;
            cameraOffsetComponent.m_Offset.z = -0.14f;
            // Store the offset in the cameraOffset variable
            cameraOffset = cameraOffsetComponent.m_Offset;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("CinemachineCameraOffset component not found on the virtual camera.");
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            // Set the tilt angle of the Cinemachine recomposer
            recomposer.m_Tilt = 31; // Assuming m_Tilt is the correct property name
            Vector3 cameraPositionWithOffset = cameraComponent.transform.position + cameraOffset;

            Ray ray = cameraComponent.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 30, Color.green, 5f);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, attackRange, enemyLayer))
            {
                Debug.Log("Raycast hit: " + hit.collider.name);
                AttackEnemy(hit.transform);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Raycast did not hit");
            }
        }
    }

    void AttackEnemy(Transform enemy)
    {
        EnemyHealth enemyHealth = enemy.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
        if (enemyHealth != null)
        {
            enemyHealth.TakeDamage(attackDamage);
            Debug.Log("Attacked the enemy with the mouse button!");
        }
    }

    void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, attackRange);
    }
}

enter image description here
enter image description here
I thought at one point it was maybe the camera angle, but I can clearly see the raycast being drawn and going through the enemy's collider. Please help! My brain hurts.

Are you seeing any debug logs?  Have you tried logging the object that hit?  Your DrawRay should multiply the direction by attackRange to visualize the actual ray.

@hijinxbassist so I'm just dumb then. I was following a tutorial and was under the impression that the attackRange was the area in which the raycast could hit, not the length of the actually raycast. Haha, thank you very much!
